# jquery disable showing website in multi tabs

Tags: jquery

how to disable showing web page in multi tab and alert for user you are opend webpage in other tab.sorry for my english

Comment: Usually not a good idea to do this as it leads to a lot of unnecessary complexity; asking this question is usually a symptom of some other problem.  What is the overall aim here, why are you trying to prevent multiple instances of the website?

Comment: I agree with Shah : it's perfectly possible to test this but it would probably end being more a nuisance than a feature the users will like. Of course it can't be seen as some anti-cheat solution as it's always easy to have a separate browser using a different IP, or any other fast hack.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to add some code here to explain what you are talking about. You control whether links are opened in a new tab or not using the target attribute in your link,

e.g

```
<a href="http://www.mysite.com/" target="_blank">Visit Link</a>
```

would open in new tab/window

```
<a href="http://www.mysite.com/" target="_self">Visit Link</a>
```

would open in the same window

(apparently this approach is no longer supported in htm5 - probably because it is generally preferred that you dont override normal browser behavior)

if using javascript:

```
 window.location = 'example.com';
```

opens link in same window

```
window.open('example.com');
```

opens a link in a new tab/window;

if you want to alert when someone opens a link in a new window/tab using jquery you could do something like this:

```
$('a').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault;
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    alert('Window opened in new tab');
    window.open(href);
});
```

You may want to add some code above to check the target attribute to see if it is set to self or blank and behave accordingly. eg.

```
if ($(this).attr('target')=='_blank'){ //do something }
```

For the record: I personally hate this sort of behavior on web pages - everyone knows how a browser works they dont need alerts to explain what has happened.. it will just annoy people using your site so try to keep this kind of thing to a minimum